# In C file reading: how do execute fgets on a same file multiple times?

Tags: c

For example;

I have a while loop that loop through the file

```
while (fgets(line, MAXLINE-1, filePointer)!=NULL){
// do something;
}
fclose(filePointer);
```

after the loop finish, if I call fgets on the same file will return me null because fgets already finish the whole file. Then how should I read through the file again if I want to use `fgets()`?

Comment: `man fseek`....

Comment: Or http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_rewind.htm

Comment: Try using rewind(FILE *stream);

Comment: Couldn't you store the line read in a variable, instead of coming and going in the file?

Comment: Aside: the -1 in `fgets(line, MAXLINE-1, filePointer)` is suspicious.  Posting more of the code would help determine its impact on this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end of the while loop what happens is that the file pointer reaches to the end of the file(known as EOF). The OS keeps a record of the position of the pointer to keep track of where you are or what your position is in the file so that it can read further from that position. All you need to do is just move that file pointer to the beginning of the file. Now there are two ways for that you can use the rewind() method or the fseek() method. This is how:

```
rewind(fp);
```

OR

```
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

use this before reading the same file again. for the record, fp refers to the file that you are trying to read

Comment: You should add that some streams do not support seeking, such as a terminals and pipes.

Comment: @chqrlie; nvm; my bad; I close my file before I rewind or fseek; and realize that I should do this before I close my file. But thanks for reply

Comment: Or, you can close the file and open it again.

Comment: yes if it is going to a terminal or something it won't work as it should.

Answer (score 3):

To reset the file pointer, you may use two approaches:

```
rewind(fp);
```

and:

```
 fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);
```

Where `fp` is the FILE pointer. You may then call `fgets()` again to read the file from its beginning.

Comment: Curious, any particular reason for `0L` versus simply `0`?

Comment: @chux I just remember I once saw it like this, so it was simply a pull from memory.

Comment: @chux [`man fseek`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fseek) is giving this example. Probably to emphasize it is taking `long`...

Comment: @EugeneSh. It is in the C spec too - for reasons that evade me other than attempting to be illustrative.  Do you see any need for it?

Comment: @chux  I don't see any for the zero case. Only if they assume one might replace `0` with some large constant and work with some older standard which actually requiring the suffix..